# Saving multiple HTML textareas in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I would like to grab the values of several textarea fields and save them to the database. For now I have four of each with different values and I want to batch save these values, the textarea fields are:

```
<textarea  name="compedia[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="specification[]"></textarea>
```

and the save function:

```
function saveCOA(){
    $labref=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $data=  $this->input->post('compedia');
    $data1=  $this->input->post('specification');
    $compedia=array(
        'labref'=>$labref, //NDQA201303001
        'compedia'=>$data,
        'specification'=>$data1
    );
    foreach ($compedia as $value) {
        $this->db->insert('coa_body',$value);  
    }

}
```

When I `print_r($value)` it returns :

```
NDQA201303001
Array ( [0] => Alphy [1] => poxy [2] => alphy [3] => poxy )
Array ( [0] => poxy [1] => alphy [2] => poxy [3] => alphy )
```

and when I try to save, it returns:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'NDQA201303001' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `coa_body` (`NDQA201303001`) VALUES ('')

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\NQCL\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

How should the syntax be so as to loop over all the textarea values and save them to the database at once?

Comment: What are the column names of `coa_body` table???

Comment: @elav the column names are labref, compedia and specification just like in the compedia array above

Comment: labref has just one value, whereas compedia and specification has array of values, So while saving in db You'll be saving labref value (i.e. `NDQA201303001`) repeatedly for each and every row???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that

```
count($data) == count($data1); //Always True!
```

If that's the case the following will work:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
    $insert_data = array(
        'labref'=>$labref, //NDQA201303001 - Same for all the rows
        'compedia'=>$data[$i],
        'specification'=>$data1[$i]
    );
    $this->db->insert('coa_body',$insert_data);
}
```

Check this Link: [**CodePad.org**](http://codepad.org/adgtNpnc)

---

**Update**:
Suggested by [**Rcpayan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2018018/rcpayan):

```
//This will reduce number of context switching,
//even though loping is doubled!
for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
    $insert_data[$i] = array(
        'labref'=>$labref, //NDQA201303001
        'compedia'=>$data[$i],
        'specification'=>$data1[$i]
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('coa_body',$insert_data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i have been looking for. Thank you

Comment: is it better using insert_batch after for?

Comment: @rcpayan I am sorry I didn't get your question...!

Comment: ok :) you used `$this->db->insert('coa_body',$insert_data);` everytime but what if i define `insert_data` as `$insert_data[] = array` and after for loop, using `$this->db->insert_batch('coa_body',$insert_data);` instead of `$this->db->insert('coa_body',$insert_data);` each time, would it be better?

Comment: Great idea...! But In this case it'll only double the looping time! So I guess its better to stick with insert inside for...

Comment: @rcpayan: In one way I feel like what you say is correct. In the solution that I've given, **Context Switching** is more! That'll reduce if we just use `insert_batch();`. So it is a good idea dude...

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, it's a bit longer but can also deal with *compedia* and *specification* not being equal. This solutions assumes a few things:

- You want the value of *labref* to be the same for each row inserted
- If the number of values for *compedia* and *specification* aren't equal, you still want to insert the row, but the 'missing' values will be set to `NULL`.

---

```
$labref             = $this->uri->segment(3);
$compedia_data      = $this->input->post('compedia');
$specification_data = $this->input->post('specification');

//Calculate which array is larger, so we can loop through all values
$max_array_size = max(count($compedia_data), count($specification_data));

//Iterate through the arrays
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_array_size; $i++)
{
    $this->db->set('labref', $labref);

    //If we still have a value(s) for compedia, then assign the value, otherwise set to NULL
    if array_key_exists($i, $compedia_data)
    {
        $this->db->set('compedia', $compedia_data[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->set('compedia', NULL);
    }        

    //If we still have a value(s) for specification, then assign the value, otherwise set to NULL
    if array_key_exists($i, $specification_data)
    {
        $this->db->set('specification', $specification_data[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->set('specification', NULL);
    }

    //Insert into table: 'coa_body'
    $this->db->insert('coa_body');
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could change the loop to assign the values to an array, then batch insert these values. This might offer better performance.

```
//Initial other relevant code is included in the example above (excluded here for brevity)
$insert_array = new array();

//Iterate through the arrays
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_array_size; $i++)
{
    $row_array           = new array();
    $row_array['labref'] = $labref;

    //If we still have a value(s) for compedia, then assign the value, otherwise set to NULL
    if array_key_exists($i, $compedia_data)
    {
        $row_array['compedia'] = $compedia_data[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $row_array['compedia'] = NULL;
    }        

    //If we still have a value(s) for specification, then assign the value, otherwise set to NULL
    if array_key_exists($i, $specification_data)
    {
        $row_array['specification'] = $specification_data[$i];
    }
    else
    {
        $row_array['specification'] = NULL;
    }

    //Add current row to the insert array, so it can be added to the database
    $insert_array[$i] = $row_array;
}

//Insert into table: 'coa_body'
$this->db->insert_batch('coa_body', $insert_array);
```